# Quiero enviar un archivo para su descarga al FrontEnd desde una API

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, base64

Tengo una API hecha en ASP.NET Core, hice una función que recibe archivos desde el FrontEnd para guardar sus datos en un base de datos en SQL Server. Ahora necesito hacer un método que envíe el archivo hacia el FrontEnd para su descarga.

Mediante un stored procedure consigo traerme el nombre del archivo, el contentType y el archivo en base64.

```
[HttpGet(nameof(Descargar))]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Descargar(int id)
        {
            byte[] bytes;
            var dbparams = new DynamicParameters();
            dbparams.Add("@IdDocumentoArchivo", id, DbType.Int32);
            EncSyDocumentoArchivo archivoDescarga = await Task.FromResult(_DocumentoArchivo.Cargar<EncSyDocumentoArchivo>("SpdEncSyDocumentoArchivoCargar", dbparams, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure));

            if (archivoDescarga.idDocumentoArchivo == id)
            {
                string link = "data:" + archivoDescarga.contentType + ";base64," + archivoDescarga.datosArchivo;
                bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(link);

                return File(bytes, archivoDescarga.contentType, archivoDescarga.nombreArchivo);

            }
            return BadRequest();
        }
```

Este código me funcionó con imágenes pequeñas de tipo png pero cuando cambio a otro tipo de archivo o la imagen es muy pesada, el archivo ya no se puede abrir al momento de descargar. Lo importante aquí es como puedo crear y mandar el archivo y que sea de cualquier tipo con los datos que tengo.

Comment: El archivo se descarga en el cliente? Sale algún error en logs del lado del servidor cuando lo descargan?

Comment: @Alfabravo El archivo si se logra descargar en el cliente aun que no se puede abrir. Cuando descargo el archivo, se abre el explorador de archivos de windows y al momento de darle al botón Guardar o Cancelar en el explorador de archivos, se apaga el API en visual studio sin razon y me aparece lo siguiente: _Se omitió la carga de símbolos. El módulo está optimizado y la opción del depurador 'Sólo mi código' está habilitada.
El programa '[10584] iisexpress.exe' terminó con código -1 (0xffffffff)._